# Visual Studio Installer Project - User's startup Folder shortcut not working?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, project, shortcut

I've made an installer project for my program, created a shortcut of my project output and put it into User's Sartup Folder. After installing the program, task manager shows random characters for my program under the startup tab. When right clicking and opening it's location, it opens AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Installer/[ProductCode] of the installer project]/RandomcharactersAsShortcutName.exe (.exe, not .lnk).

When I check my startup folder, the shortcut (.lnk) is there as instended, but not used for some reason.

When uninstalling the program, it deletes the shortcut from the startup folder, so it knows it's there.

When I don't create a shortcut in the user's startup folder, it still creates this Installer folder with the randomly named .exe in AppData, but task Manager doesn't detect it as a startup program.

How do I make the project not create this folder, or how can I edit the name that appears in the task manager startup menu?

EDIT: after restarting my PC and rebuilding countless of times, the path is now C:/Windows/Installer/[ProductCode] - Wat

Comment: Have you put it to the path like this? `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: Win + R and then input shell:startup to open the start up folder, the path you provided looks not correct?

Comment: Checked the path, it successfully creates a startup folder shortcut, but for some reason, it uses the .exe file in the mentioned folder, now in Windows/Installer/[folder]. Deleting this folder removes my program from the startup list, even though there is a shortcut under shell:startup